# Sachin Tendulkar's bowling record

Tags: cricket, trivia, records

In a YouTube video, when I was watching Sachin Tendulkar's feat as a bowler, one of the commentators commented that Sachin holds the record for dismissing Inzamam-ul-haq the most number of times. How true is that?

How many times has the little master has had the best of the former Pakistani skipper?

Comment: I dont understand the logic behind people closing this as localized. If this is too localized, what would be the question you would ask in a Q&A forum for sports page. Localized was used as an option in SO to denote that the problem was very specific to the person who asked question and will not benefit anyone apart from him. I dont understand how can it be used here. OP is not talking about his personal record here to say that this is localized. It is a questions about trivia and records.

Comment: Any reason as to why the third question was removed ?

Comment: Even I am wondering that. I have seen a lot of trivia questions here and this is the only one which got close votes. Probably something in question is provoking some people.

Comment: See meta: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/354/too-localized-question-evaluation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many times has the little master had the best of the former
>   Pakistani skipper?

As per [this](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/35320.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=dis_dismissals;template=results;type=bowling;view=batsman_summary), Sachin has dismissed Inzamam 8 times in international cricket which is the max no of dismissal Sachin has on any batsman. He has also dismissed Lara, Waugh, Moin Khan and A Flower 4 times each.

> One of the commentators commented that Sachin holds the record for
>   dismissing Inzamam-ul-haq the most number of times. How true is that?

Even though Sachin has dismissed him 8 times, he is not the bowler who has dismissed Inzamam max no of times. As per [this list](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/40570.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=dis_bowler;outs=1;template=results;type=batting;view=dismissal_list), Muralidharan and Vaas has dismissed him 12 times each followed by Warne who dismissed him 11 times.

If you consider only ODIs, Venkatesh Prasad and Jayasuriya has dismissed him 8 times each whereas Sachin has dismissed him 7 times. So the above statement is not completely true which says Sachin holds the record for dismissing Inzamam most no of times, even though it is a record for Sachin since he hasn't dismissed anyother batsman more than 8 times.

Since the third question was removed adding something related to that as trivia,

**Trivia:**
In terms of economy rate, Sachin is among the top T20 bowlers of India as per [this](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=3;orderby=economy_rate;team=6;template=results;type=bowling). He has played only one match and has match figures of 12/1 at an economy rate of 4.8 against SA which is second in the list behind Murali Vijay with 4.5.

Comment: Murali Vijay has now replaced Sachin at the top of that list :)